# Erro "Element linear layout must be declared"

Tags: android, android-layout

Gostaria de uma orientação por gentileza sou iniciante no Android Studio. Procurei em muitos fóruns e muitas pesquisas e não encontrei nenhuma solução faz dias.

Quando eu crio um arquivo dentro da pasta *drawable* acontece seguinte erro:

> Element linear layout must be declared.

Notei que isso também acontece quando eu crio uma pasta com arquivo ou somente arquivo fora da pasta **layout** mas dentro da **res**. Já os arquivos dentro da **layout** não acontece nenhum tipo de erro quando crio algum novo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que quer criar um layout fora da pasta layout?

Comment: @ramaral ia perguntar o mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os arquivos de layout (RelativeLayout e LinearLayout) devem ficar dentro da pasta **res/layout**.

Nessa pasta drawable você coloca arquivos de imagens e de Drawable Resources, como por exemplo: layer-list, shape, selector e etc...

Você pode dar uma conferida em todos elementos aceitos nessa pasta drawable na documentação do Android: [Drawable Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação.